# Is there a snowflake function that gives the timestamp format as 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a timestamp column that as values as below, But user expects it to be in the format of 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'. Is there any way we can get it.

| Date |
| --- |
| 2022-03-01 16:34:02 |
| 2022-06-14 22:14:01 |
| 2022-01-06 23:57:05 |

Tried below query but didnt work.
select to_timestamp(cast(date as string),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') from table

Error - Can't parse '2022-03-01 16:34:02' as timestamp with format 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'.

Answer (score 0):

Try `to_varchar(timestamp_col, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')`.
Sample code -

```
select to_varchar('2013-04-05 01:02:03'::timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

[image]